# Combining php:7.2-alpine with nginx in ond Dockerfile

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I have a need to combine the php:7.2 alpine with nginx in one dockerfile( in one docker image ) for production deployment of laravel app.

So I tried my way and I can only add nginx package. I can't find any nginx conf file in my image. I found many someone's images in docker hub. I tried a lot with this images and not working well.

Here is my docker file.

```
FROM php:7.2-alpine

RUN apk upgrade --update -q \
  && apk --no-cache -q add openssl zip unzip git mysql-client vim coreutils freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo libltdl libmcrypt-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
  NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql opcache zip calendar \
  && apk del --no-cache -q freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apk --update add \
    supervisor

RUN apk add --update nginx && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/client-body

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#COPY website /usr/share/nginx/html
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY ./workspace-api /var/www
COPY ./workspace-api/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
ADD ./workspace-api/root /etc/crontabs/
ADD ./workspace-api/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

RUN composer install
RUN chmod -R 755  /var/www


RUN chmod +x /var/www/supervisor.sh
RUN /var/www/supervisor.sh

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

PS: I have docker-compose file for multi container app. But in this case, I only need to build all in one image for laravel.

Comment: Why can’t you use a separate Nginx container?  That would be easier to build and manage, and you could use an unmodified `nginx` image plus local config files.

Comment: You can refere to this example it will help you:
https://hub.docker.com/r/trafex/alpine-nginx-php7/dockerfile

Comment: I know how to use with separate nignx container. The main reason I have trouble is to combine all in one in one container